# Get grandparent-element in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app

I have a Hub-Element and I want to navigate though this elements with a touch/click on a hub-section. As the HubSection-Elements are not click-able (only through "SectionHeaderClick", which produces an rather ugly "See More" link), I've made the GridView clickable.

```
<Frame x:Name="frame">
  <Hub VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
     <HubSection Width="250" x:Name="section1"  IsHeaderInteractive="True" >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <GridView IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="{x:Bind MainPageVM.click}">
                            <RelativePanel>
                                <Image x:Name="image" Source="Assets/1.png" Width="Auto" Height="250"  />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="page1" Text="page1" />
                            </RelativePanel>
                        </GridView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HubSection>

                //....
         </Hub>             
</Frame>
```

In my ViewModel the "click"-method should navigate the frame to page1

```
public void hubClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
   GridView gridview = sender as GridView;
   // "GrandGrandParent" equivalent ?
   Frame frame = gridview.GrandGrandParent;
   frame.Navigate(typeof(View.page1));           
}
```

So basically I have to access the frame element in a MVVM-style. How can I access the frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VisualTreeHelper Method GetParent() in your event

Here is link [GetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getparent)

var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);

Comment: But the problem is that "getParent" would give me the "DataTemplate" element, I need the "frame" element, which isn't the parent.

Comment: Call that method again and again until you get a desired element

Comment: You can write a recursive function with generic type like this public <T> GetParent(element){var parent =VisualTreeHelper.GetParent();if(parent is T){return parrnt}else{GetParent<Frame>(parent)}

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM pattern you typically navigate from a view model layer which you can do without accessing a view layer from the view model layer by passing the frame wrapped in a navigation service interface into the view model. That's if you are actually using the MVVM pattern to do things like unit testing. If you don't plan to unit test navigation - you can typically expose a static property that points to your frame on the App class.